# How to preserve feature properties when using flatten() in Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

In the code below (from [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-flatten)), I want to export countiesClimate to Drive as a shapefile. To do this I first use flatten() to convert a feature collection of feature collections to a feature collection of features. But when I do this the 'date' property that I assign in the function disappears. Instead, the columns of the feature collections in countiesClimate become the properties of the features in countiesClimate.flatten().

So my question is: how do I make the properties countiesClimate carry over to countiesClimate.flatten()? Or, how do I create a new column in countiesClimate? (so the data gets carried over to countiesClimate.flatten())

```
var counties = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2018/Counties')
                   .filter('STATEFP == "35"');

var climate = ee.ImageCollection('IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE')
                  .filterDate('2020-01', '2020-04');

var countiesClimate = climate.map(function(image) {
  return image.reduceRegions({
    collection: counties,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 5000,
    crs: 'EPSG:4326'
  })
  // ***this is the new line of code which is saved as a property, not a column, and is not carried over to countiesClimate.flatten(): ***
  .set('date', image.get('system:time_end'));
});

print('FeatureCollection of FeatureCollections', countiesClimate);

// What I want is for the output of flatten() to include the 'date' property that I assign in the above function
print('Flattened FeatureCollection of FeatureCollections',
      countiesClimate.flatten());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map a function over the results of the `reduceRegions` call to set the date on each feature, instead of on the collection wrapper.

```
var countiesClimate = climate.map(function(image) {
  return image.reduceRegions({
    collection: counties,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 5000,
    crs: 'EPSG:4326'
  }).map(function(f) {
      return f.set('date', image.get('system:time_end'))
  })
})
```

Comment: That did it - thank you!